# websocket doesn't upgrade while hosted on IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis, java-websocket

I have a java application which use Websocket to communicate. Everything works fine in development environment but websocket doesn't work in production environment.Could anyone tell me the steps to config IIS. Now I have already enable websocket protocol in IIS but it still doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.
I am using Windows Server 2016, Tomcat 9.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you hosted  your web application on IIS? You said you used tomcat9. Besides, I suggest you could use F12 develop tool to see the details error message when you receive the upgrade response form the server.

Comment: I used isapi redirector to host web application in IIS. I have seen that ajp13 doesn't support Websocket protocol. Is there any method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many methods and still couldn't connet WebSocket in remote browser eventhough worked on local server. So I have changed production environment to CentOS and WebSocket worked.